# range searches retrieve data faster in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables.

```
create table person
(
    ID integer,
    a_number varchar(9),
    first_name varchar(25),
    last_name varchar(25),
    etc ...
);
```

```
create table number_in_ranges_mv
(   range_id number(9,0) , 
    begin_range number(9,0), 
    end_range number(9,0)   
 )
```

I need to retrieve all the `a_number`s that are in a specific ranges.

I have the following query

```
select nums.range_id, count(p. a_number)
from number_in_ranges nums
left join person p on to_number(p. a_number)
between nums.begin_range and nums.end_range 
group by nums.range_id;
```

but due to the `person` table having around 100 mill records this query is very slow.

Here is the query plan

```
Plan hash value: 497207773
 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                | Name               | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT         |                    |  8899 |   234K|       |   594K (32)| 00:00:24 |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY           |                    |  8899 |   234K|       |   594K (32)| 00:00:24 |
|   2 |   MERGE JOIN OUTER       |                    |  1918M|    48G|       |   520K (22)| 00:00:21 |
|   3 |    SORT JOIN             |                    |  8899 |   147K|       |    28   (4)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     MAT_VIEW ACCESS FULL | NUMBER_IN_RANGES_MV|  8899 |   147K|       |    27   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |    FILTER                |                    |       |       |       |            |          |
|*  6 |     SORT JOIN            |                    |    86M|   822M|  2642M|   412K  (1)| 00:00:17 |
|   7 |      INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| PERSON_ANBR_IDX    |    86M|   822M|       | 67694   (1)| 00:00:03 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   5 - filter("NUMS"."END_RANGE">=TO_NUMBER("A_NUMBER"(+)))
   6 - access("NUMS"."BEGIN_RANGE"<=TO_NUMBER("A_NUMBER"(+)))
       filter("NUMS"."BEGIN_RANGE"<=TO_NUMBER("A_NUMBER"(+)))
```

How can I improve this query?

Thank you!

Comment: please run an explain plan and show the results.

Comment: `to_number(p. a_number)` is a performance killer. Can't you convert that column to `number(9,0)` in advance?

Comment: What percentage of rows in `person` do you estimate will match a range?

Comment: Why is `person.a_number` defined as a `varchar2`?  That prevents you from using a regular index on that column and probably screws up the statistics.  Are you expecting that (most) every row in `person` is going to be in at least 1 range?  In which case you'd need to read 100 M rows every time which isn't going to be cheap (I don't know if by "very slow" you mean it takes hours when you're hoping for 10 minutes or if it takes several minutes and you want it to come back in less than a second to populate a web page).

Comment: @JustinCave it takes over 20 hours. Its a scheduled job that runs overnight. `person.a_number` it's defined as a varchar2 for many other reasons that is not up to me.

Comment: @TheImpaler no, that column can't be converted in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If each range has a low percentage of related rows in the `person` table (less than 5%, ideally less than 1%) then a *functional index* can help the query performance. A straight index on `a_number` won't help at all.

The most straighforward solution would be to add an index on the conversion expression. For example:

```
create index ix1 on person (to_number(a_number));
```

Now, if for every range the percentage of matching rows is higher than 5% then this index won't probably be of help. In that case there would still be hope for a *merge join*, though, but that's a different story.

Answer (score 0):

Though you can have an index on range_id, a_number etc basis column used intensively but alternatively you can Select only a_number column from person like below in left join to improve the existing performance to some extent

```
 select nums.range_id, count(p. a_number)
 from number_in_ranges nums
  left join (Select distinct a_number from person) p on 
  to_number(p. 
  a_number)
   between nums.begin_range and nums.end_range 
 group by nums.range_id;
```

Comment: But that changes the results.  If 10 people have the same `a_number` value, the original query would count them 10 times in the range.  Once you `distinct` them out, you'd have a count of only 1.  If there are a relatively small number of distinct `a_number` values, I suppose it might make sense to pre-aggregate the data but I'd want to see the actual query plan first.

Comment: @JustinCave `a_number` is unique. There is an index on `a_number` as well.

Comment: @Mariana you can run the above with the limit 10 to test on existing as well as above query there should be a significant difference in the query run time